# Optimized (memory-wise) implementation of full graph in C++

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-management, graph

I need to implement Watts-Strogatz algorithm and I'm running into some problems with creating a full graph. The way I'm implemeting it, it takes up so much memory and I need to work on big systems so that is a problem.

I'm creating a matrix called lattice for my n nodes with their n - 1 = k neighbours. For eg. let's say n = 7. My lattice will look like:

```
1 6 2 5 3 4 
2 0 3 6 4 5
3 1 4 0 5 6
4 2 5 1 6 0
5 3 6 2 0 1
6 4 0 3 1 2
0 5 1 4 2 3
```

And now the code to create it.

This is main.cpp:

```
#include "lattice.h"
#include <vector>

int main() {

    /*
     * initial parameters
     */
    int n = 7; //number of agents MUST BE ODD
    int k = 6; //number of agents with whom we wire; N - 1 for full graph
                   // NEEDS TO BE EVEN

    int** lattice = new int* [n];

    /*
     * creating ring lattice
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        lattice[i] = new int [k];
    }
    createRingLattice (n, k, lattice);

    delete[](lattice);

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the function createRingLattice:

```
void createRingLattice (int n, int k, int** lattice) {
    /*
     * setting up ring lattice
     */
    //table of the nearest neighbours
    //next iN previous iP
    int* iP = new int [n];
    int* iN = new int [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        iP[i] = i - 1;
        iN[i] = i + 1;
    }
    //boundary conditions
    iP[0] = n - 1;
    iN[n - 1] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int countP = 0;
        int countN = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                if (i + countN > n - 1) {
                    lattice[i][j] = iN[i + countN - n];
                } else {
                    lattice[i][j] = iN[i + countN];
                }
                countN++;
            }
            if (j % 2 == 1 ) {
                if (i - countP < 0) {
                    lattice[i][j] = iP[n + i - countP];
                } else {
                    lattice[i][j] = iP[i - countP];
                }
                countP++;
            }
        }
    }

    delete[](iN);
    delete[](iP);
}
```

**First question:**
Is there a way to implement this with much less memory usage?

**Second question:**
I've seen people implementing graphs with adjacency list ([this one for example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/)) but I'm wondering if it's acctually more optimized than my implemantation? It does use pointers as well and I'm not the expert so it's hard for me to determine whether it's better when it comes to memory usage.

Note: I'm not concerned about speed at the moment.

Comment: You should flatten your matrix, ditch raw arrays and use a `std::vector`. Using appropriately-sized type instead of `int` also could not hurt. Still, the matrix takes `O(N^2)` memory, if the large graph is sparse, adjacency lists could save memory. Still, if you mean this seriously, why reinvent the wheel? Why not use any graph library?

Comment: Just a hint: After 13 years of C++ programming, I don't remember a single case where allocating arrays using `new[]` was ever necesssary. Use a `std::vector<>`. That would also avoid the memory leak you have, which may well be the cause of your memory issues.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions! I'll see which one works best and try to use a graph library.